# How can I create a form that automatically hides or displays certain questions based on previous answers?

Tags: workflow, form, content-approval, approval-process

What is a good reference on how to create a work-flow based form?

i.e. The form has ten fields, and the first five fields show up by default, but the next five fields show up only when a user has selected a specific answer in one of the first five fields?

Alternatively, is there a way to create a form and only display the first five fields, and once the request has been approved, to redirect the person who originally filled out the form to complete it with five additional fields?

Thanks!
Adam (and Kristel)

Answer (score 3):

The survey list can handle this out of the box.

If that doesn't suit the need, then you can create a custom list with all your form fields and create a custom InfoPath form to show/hide content or use javascript/jQuery on the form pages to show/hide infomation.

If you want it to be a document, then you can use a form library and create your own InfoPath form.

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you could use a Survey list? The Survey list type allows for conditional questions, which sounds like what you are looking for. Answers to a given question can be evaulated and then used to serve up matching questions in resonse.